# Laravel Eloquent AS keyword

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use the keyword AS to combine two columns so I can sort on that column.

This is the full query as it at the moment.

```
$quotes = Quote::where('created_at', '>=', $date)
        ->where('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59')
        ->order_by('upvotes', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5);
```

I would like to do

```
->order_by('(downvotes - upvotes) as votes', 'desc')
```

Thank you.

## Solution

Seems as though using DB::raw() is the only way to do it, Laravel/Eloquent just doesn't understand the AS.

Working solution is

```
 $quotes = Quote::select(array('id', DB::raw('(downvotes - upvotes) as votes'), 'upvotes', 'downvotes', 'etc')) // Rest of column needed.
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $date)
        ->where('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59')
        ->order_by('votes', 'asc')
        ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: How does the raw sql query look like? Try using [`DB::raw()`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/database.php#L123).

Comment: Using DB::raw() in a select() worked, thank you.

Comment: It will actually understand AS just fine. The issue is with the subtraction operator '-'. Using DB::raw() as you did is the correct way to handle that situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Quote::where('created_at', '>=', $date)
        ->select(array('id',DB::raw('(downvotes - upvotes) as votes'))) //and what you need
        ->where('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59')
        ->order_by('upvotes', 'desc')
        ->order_by('votes', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the `(downvotes - upvotes) as votes` gets read as `SELECT id', '(downvotes' AS 'upvotes)', 'quotes',`, thus throwing an error.

Comment: Probably using DB:raw is necessary. Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

```
$selectdata = DB::table('TableDetails')
            ->leftJoin('TableStatus', 'TableDetails.TableID', '=', 'TableStatus.TableID')
            ->leftJoin('LoginUser', 'TableStatus.WaiterLoginID', '=', 'LoginUser.LoginID')
            ->leftJoin('UserRole', 'LoginUser.UserRoleID', '=', 'UserRole.UserRoleID')
            ->select('LoginUser.UserName','UserRole.UserRoleName','TableStatus.TableStatus','TableStatus.TableTimeStatus','TableStatus.WaiterLoginID','TableDetails.TableSeatCount - TableStatus.TableSeatOccupied AS TableRemainingCount')
            ->get();
```

Just live a 'Space' before and after Minus symbol it worked for me.