# Using AS Keyword in Laravel Eloquent Join Query In Main Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to use `AS` keyword in Laravel Eloquent Model like that:

Here my sample query:

```
User::find(1)
    ->select("name", "age")
    ->join("profile as p", "p.user_id", "=", "users.id")
    ->orderBy("name", "asc")
    ->get();
```

Expected usage `u.id` instead of `users.id` on joins with main table/model

```
->join("profile as p", "p.user_id", "=", "u.id")
```

Is there such a feature, is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent AS keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158139/laravel-eloquent-as-keyword)

Comment: @Fawzan I saw that and it is so old question (5 years ago) and it is not related to my question. My question is about that using as keyword on main table/model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `from` method in eloquent like that

```
User::from('users as u')->find(1)
    ->select("name", "age")
    ->join("profile as p", "p.user_id", "=", "u.id")
    ->orderBy("name", "asc")
    ->get();
```

see this query eloquent method [here](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php#L365)

Comment: I knew this from method, but I didn't think it would work with the Eloquent, thank you!